# Como criar um jogo comercial usando modelos prontos na Unity sem violar direitos autorais?

Tags: jogos, licença

Vou criar um jogo pago usando Unity 5, mas vou usar modelos já prontos e gratuitos para isso.
Terei que pagar ou colocar o nome dos desenvolvedores dos modelos no jogo ou eu posso usar sem problemas de direitos autorais?

Answer (score 5):

Isso vai depender de qual é a [licença](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_copyright_license) em que os modelos gratuitos foram disponibilizados. Se essa informação não estiver disponível junto aos modelos, a única maneira de saber vai ser perguntando direto para os autores originais. A não ser que o autor original dê permissão explicitamente, você não deve assumir que pode usar um modelo apenas por ele ser gratuito.

Por exemplo, um tipo de licença bem comum de encontrar para assets gratuitos são as licenças [Creative Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license). Nas licenças Creative Commons menos restritivas a única coisa que os autores originais pedem de você é que você inclua o nome deles nos créditos de seu jogo (CC BY). Já nas licenças Creative Commons mais restritivas pode ser que os autores dos modelos proíbam o uso dos modelos para fins comerciais (CC BY-NC).